# Two-way ANOVA, what to do next?

Tags: anova, spss

I used a 3x2 between-subject ANOVA to examine the effect of colour (three levels: colourless, light red, and dark red) and odour (odourless or not) on perceived sweetness. The results indicated significant main effects for colour and odour and also a significant interaction of these two factors. I don't know what to do next.

- What post-hoc tests can I run to understand this interaction?
- How can I do it in SPSS?

Comment: This is more difficult to read than is necessary. You may find it quicker to ignore upper case and be casual about punctuation when you type, but when you are asking a favour, it's a better tactic to write with more attention to the usual conventions.

Comment: you are totally rght but im in a very bad situation because tommorow i have to submit and i dont know what to to do. thank you again

Comment: You don't *have* to do anything. If you are lost and in a hurry and since the design is not very complicated and all effects are significant, just interpret the pattern of means directly.

Comment: Thank you Gahel Laurans  but my supervisor told me its not ok that and i have to run independent or paired t tests to see the differences from the interaction.to see exactly if e.g dark red colour with strawberry odour enhanced more the perceived sweetness than did the light red colour with strawberry odour and if for example no colour with do odour did not have any significance difference with the scores of no colour with strawbeery odour. is there any other solution? than you in advanceagain

Comment: hello, i would like to ask how i check the simple main effects ? i used 3x2 anova and i find significant interaction? whixh post hoc test to use ? 
thank you in advance

Comment: Gaël Laurans, it's certainly not OK to just interpret the mean differences as though they were all significant on the basis that both main effects and the interaction are significant. This would have been possible only in a 2x2 design, not a 3x2 design.

Comment: patric  what i can do then? how to check the simple effects.what else to do? can you help me pleasE?

Comment: Patrick Coulombe, that's not even possible in a 2x2 design.  What is possible is to interpret the means through the interaction, which is how I interpreted Gaël Laurans comment.  That's always straightforward with a 2x2 and usually pretty easy with a 2x3 but the poster hasn't put them up so we cannot know.

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe I am not arguing you should believe they are all “significant” (as if it was the only thing that mattered), I am saying you should *look* at them.

Answer (score 3):

This comes up frequently on the site.  Odour has an effect, colour has an effect, and they interact.  Therefore, the degree of odour's effect varies across colour.  You know this now.  Look at the means and describe the amount of effects.

Let's say that you checked the effect of odour for light red and it was significant but it wasn't for colourless. What does that tell you? It actually doesn't tell you anything meaningful. It doesn't tell you there's a difference between those conditions because you didn't test [that](http://www.invivoadvertising.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Significance-or-Not.pdf). And, you already knew there was a main effect of odour, did it suddenly go away? What does tell you there's a difference between the conditions is the interaction.  What happens if all of your simple effect tests are significant?  Does that help you interpret your interaction?  No.  You can't infer anything across your conditions from those simple effects.

Please add a table of your 6 means to your question.  It is possible that you might need to test some kind of subset of the data but simple effects aren't going to get you meaningful info.  If you need anything, more than likely you'd need a 2x2 interaction or a direct test of the differences among effects.  But it's doubtful you even need that.

Comment: thank you very much. so, pairwise comparisons i run with syntax and gave me mean differences among the subtypes of factors in different conditions it is ok ??

Comment: It doesn't really tell you anything.  You should really post the means you have in your question.